# Why Strange extra vertical lines appear in eps format of ParametricPlot and how to remove them?

Tags: export, eps-format, plotting

Using the following code, we can generate the parametric plot of func1 and func2 as a function of r:

```
    func1=(104832. r^9 - 70560. r^10 + 8064. r^11 + 4368. r^12 - 1444.8 r^13 + 
 168 r^14 + 8 r^15 + 0.149718 r^16)/(32 \[Pi] r^15);

func2=(128 r^15 (29484. r^2 - 13230. r^3 + 1134. r^4 + 491.4 r^5 - 
    135.45 r^6 + (27 r^7)/2 + 0.00935739 r^9) - 
 144 r^8 (6552. r^9 - 4410. r^10 + 504. r^11 + 273. r^12 - 
    90.3 r^13 + (21 r^14)/2 + 0.00935739 r^16))/(11520000 \[Pi] r^15);

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{func1, func2}, {r, 0, 150}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.008]}, MaxRecursion -> 10]
 , PlotRange -> {{.1637, .167}, {.16, .22}}
 , Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> .4, ImageSize -> 400, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times", 
   Style -> "Roman"},
 FrameStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> None, Axes -> None]
```

The resulting plot in 11.0.1.0 version of Mathematica is: (It is what I expected and seems true. Maple gives the same plot.)

[image]

During plotting this curve, Mathematica gives 2 errors:

```
 Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^15 encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression (0. ComplexInfinity)/\[Pi] encountered.
```

The problem is when I export this figure to eps format, 2 vertical lines appear which I don't know the reason (may be because of infinities) and my question is how to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try  `Show[ParametricPlot[{func1, func2} // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {r, 0, 150}...`
to force symbolic  plotargument.

Comment: @Neumann: Thanks. This removes the errors, but still the vertical lines appear in eps format of the plot.